# Гарантированная доставка сообщений

Tags: rabbitmq

Сейчас разбираюсь с RabbitMQ. Ну и везде куча слов, типа сообщение после попадания в очередь живет, пока не будет обработано. Сообщение переживает как перезапуск читателя, так и всего брокера и т.д.

Но, если я правильно понимаю, все это работает, если сообщение уже попало в брокер. А если между писателем и удаленным брокером находится плохой канал связи, то о гарантированной доставке сообщений должен беспокоиться сам писатель. Он должен сам периодически опрашивать доступность брокера и самостоятельно буферизировать неотправленные сообщения.

Вопрос - нельзя ли эту заботу переложить на сам RabbitMQ? Может поднять как-то второго брокера на локальной машине писателя и настроить репликацию?

Неотправленные сообщения должны переживать полный перезапуск компьютера писателя. Сейчас у меня все реализовано на своем протоколе. Но может можно как-то напрячь сам RabbitMQ?

Comment: Но второй брокер тоже может упасть по какой-нибудь причине и сообщение в него тоже может не попасть. Вообще, согласно [задаче двух генералов](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2) решить проблему невозможно даже теоретически. Можно лишь попытаться уменьшить вероятность потерь

Comment: @andreymal считаем, что вероятность падения локального брокера равна нулю

Answer (score 1):

Если вы пишете на asp.net core, то для решения этой задачи можете воспользоваться фреймворком MassTransit - по-умолчанию, писатель в MassTransit ждёт подтверждения `Ack` от RabbitMQ для гарантированной отправки сообщения (разумеется, ценой уменьшения производительности отправки).

Также, фреймворк обладает рядом других фич, которые делают работу с RabbitMQ не такой низкоуровневой - например, повторный приём сообщения читателем (в случае возникновения какой-то временной проблемы на его стороне) настраивается в показанном ниже примере. При этом, если принимающее приложение вдруг стало останавливаться и стали срабатывать токены отмены, то сообщение просто вернётся обратно в очередь и будет доставлено другому доступному получателю.

```
IRabbitMqHost host = cfg.Host(secrets.MessageBusHost, secrets.MessageBusVHost, h =>
{
    h.Username(secrets.MessageBusLogin);
    h.Password(secrets.MessageBusPassword);
});

cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, PrivateServiceQueueName, e =>
{
    e.UseMessageRetry(x =>
    {
        x.Handle<OperationCanceledException>();
        x.Interval(2, 500);
    });

    e.Consumer<TestRequestConsumer>(provider);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, но у меня не .net. И вопрос не в фрейморках, а в функционале самого RabbitMQ